# Keep array rows where a column value is found in a second flat array

Tags: php, arrays, filter, array-filter, array-intersect

I have an array, `$arr1` with 5 columns as such:

```
 key    id  name    style   age whim
 0      14  bob     big     33  no
 1      72  jill    big     22  yes
 2      39  sue     yes     111 yes
 3      994 lucy    small   23  no
 4      15  sis     med     24  no
 5      16  maj     med     87  yes
 6      879 Ike     larg    56  no
 7      286 Jed     big     23  yes
```

This array is in a cache, not a database.

I then have a second array with a list of id values -

```
$arr2 = array(0=>14, 1=>72, 2=>8790)
```

How do I filter `$arr1` so it returns only the rows with the id values in `$arr2`?

I have tried to use filter function (below), array_search, and several others but cannot figure out how to make it work.

```
$resultingArray = [];  // create an empty array to hold rows
$filter_function = function ($row) use ($arr2) {
    foreach ($arr2 as $arr) {
        return ($row['id'] == $arr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This whole task can be accomplished with just one slick, native function call -- `array_uintersect()`.

Because the two compared parameters in the custom callback may come either input array, try to access from the `id` column and if there isn't one declared, then fallback to the parameter's value.

Under the hood, this function performs sorting while evaluating as a means to improve execution time / processing speed.  I expect this approach to outperform iterated calls of `in_array()` purely from a point of minimized function calls.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UHZ04))

```
var_export(
    array_uintersect(
        $arr1,
        $arr2,
        fn($a, $b) =>
            ($a['id'] ?? $a)
            <=>
            ($b['id'] ?? $b)
    )
);
```

Comment: @ian I am a late poster on this question, so I didn't earn any of the early upvote handouts.  I would like to clarify, in case my answer doesn't explain well enough, that my answer is efficient because it doesn't perform array scans in a loop.  DecentDabbler's and Erwin's solutions perform partial (potentially full array scans) on each iteration of their loop and that can be costly.  user2182349 was on the right track, but performed the filtration process on temporary values instead of temporary keys and thus had to call a `foreach()` loop to generate the desired output array.

Comment: One final note is that if you don't care about the temporary keys, you can skip the final call of `array_values()` and move on to the next process in your code.

Comment: @ian and mickmackusa: yes, this answer is considerably faster than my solution, especially when dealing with a large cache set and a large filter set.

Comment: @mickmackusa and Decent Dabbler:  Thanks to you both. I have edited my code above to show how I used array_search to fix my problem. BUT, I am interested if this method can be applied to make it more efficient. Can either of you tell by looking at my updated function?

Comment: @ian the way you are using `array_search()` is not "zero-safe"  because your condition is using a loose comparison on the result of the search, a (true) `0` return value will be incorrectly evaluated as false.  You need to make a literal/strict check on `false` to use this function call properly.  Furthermore, I am again clarifying that using an iterated `array_search()` or `in_array()` method is not as efficient as my method that does a single comparison on the two arrays.  Please use my method for best efficiency.

Comment: @ian if you want to have a separate array of just the intersecting keys, then you can/should remove the `array_values()` call from my method, and just call `array_keys()` on my result array and simply declare that result to a new variable.  My answer truly is the right way to go about this.

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa. I believe you and I do have a large cache so am looking for efficient solutions. It's just I am fairly new to arrays so still trying to piece stuff together.

Comment: @ian I am happy to explain as much as I can.  When SO is treated like a classroom, everyone wins!  Here is a demo that shows how your current method will yield unexpected results.  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ec343b847710d511f444ba2d085bc41bcf0a83a6

Comment: @mickmackusa that's interesting. It does that because it cannot identify the 0 index?

Comment: @ian here is a slightly modified version of my answer to create the two arrays that you desire: https://3v4l.org/4hR0C

Comment: @ian There is a pink Warning box in the manual on this point: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php  You MUST explicitly compare using `!==false` so that a returned key of zero is not mistreated ("type-juggled" by php).  This same requirement exists elsewhere in php, of the top of my head `strpos()` needs this same treatment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159949/discussion-between-ian-and-mickmackusa).

Comment: @mickmackusa In the example above, I flipped $arr1 and swapped out `return (array_search($row['id'], $arr2));` with `return array_intersect_key(array_column($arr1,null,'id'),$arr2);` but that didn't get it. Is my existing code salvageable to use yours?

Any idea how I would apply your intersection to the existing function?

Comment: I have to say I am less comfortable with your function assigned to a variable -- I simply don't code with that style.  It's not to say that it is wrong, I just find it harder to follow.  I recommend the style that I have provided in my latest demo.  I think future eyes on your code will find it simple to follow too.

Comment: 5 years later ... I have completely rewritten my answer with a more direct and elegant approach.

Comment: @mickmackusa I notice that my freshly migrated answer is a duplicate of what you "completely rewrote" over last year. ^_^ Just as well, we have a broader spectrum of possibilities back in the view again. I'm wondering if there's any sort of penalty to "massive null-coalescence", which is a clever way to handle the intersection of two asymmetric arrays.

Comment: @Markus Well, making modern benchmarks and comparing potential techniques is probably the final frontier on Stack Overflow.  Because there isn't much that hasn't been covered by this Q&A over more than a decade, we can only hope to sharpen the existing advice.  I think your diligent posting style caters to this endeavor.  Sometimes performance is the most important concern for researchers. I often strive for directness, lowest time complexity, and elegance (which can be at odds at times).  Specific to this task, data distribution might make one time complexity algorithm better than another.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it, provided I've understood your question and data structure correctly:

```
$dataArray = [
  [ 'key' => 0, 'id' => 14  , 'name' => 'bob'  , 'style' => 'big'   , 'age' => 33  , 'whim' => 'no'  ],
  [ 'key' => 1, 'id' => 72  , 'name' => 'jill' , 'style' => 'big'   , 'age' => 22  , 'whim' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'key' => 2, 'id' => 39  , 'name' => 'sue'  , 'style' => 'yes'   , 'age' => 111 , 'whim' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'key' => 3, 'id' => 994 , 'name' => 'lucy' , 'style' => 'small' , 'age' => 23  , 'whim' => 'no'  ],
  [ 'key' => 4, 'id' => 15  , 'name' => 'sis'  , 'style' => 'med'   , 'age' => 24  , 'whim' => 'no'  ],
  [ 'key' => 5, 'id' => 16  , 'name' => 'maj'  , 'style' => 'med'   , 'age' => 87  , 'whim' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'key' => 6, 'id' => 879 , 'name' => 'Ike'  , 'style' => 'larg'  , 'age' => 56  , 'whim' => 'no'  ],
  [ 'key' => 7, 'id' => 286 , 'name' => 'Jed'  , 'style' => 'big'   , 'age' => 23  , 'whim' => 'yes' ]
];

$filterArray = [14, 72, 879];
$resultArray = array_filter( $dataArray, function( $row ) use ( $filterArray ) {
  return in_array( $row[ 'id' ], $filterArray );
} );
```

<sup>[View this example on eval.in](https://eval.in/908001)</sup>

---

However, your question appears to suggest this data might be coming from a database; is that correct? If so, perhaps it's more efficient to pre-filter the results at the database-level. Either by adding a field in the SELECT query, that represents a boolean value whether a row matched your filter ids, or by simply not returning the other rows at all.

Answer (score 1):

One way is with `foreach` loop with `array_search()`

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr1 as $value) {                            // Loop thru $arr1
    if (array_search($value['id'], $arr2) !== false) { // Check if id is in $arr2
        $result[] = $value;                            // Push to result if true
    }
}

// print result
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

As @DecentDabbler mentioned - if the data is coming out of a database, using an **IN** on your **WHERE** will allow you to retrieve only the relevant data.

Another way to filter is to use array functions

- **array_column** extracts the value of the *id* column into an array
- **array_intersect** returns the elements which are in both $arr1['id'] and $arr2
- **array_flip** flips the resulting array such that the indices into $arr1 indicate the elements in both $arr1 and $arr2

  ```
  $arr1 = [ [ 'id' => 14, 'name' => 'bob'],
          ['id' =>  72, 'name' => 'jill'],
          ['id' =>  39, 'name' => 'sue'],
          ['id' => 994, 'name' => 'lucy'],
          ['id' => 879, 'name'=> 'large']];

  $arr2 = [ 14,72,879 ];

  $intersection = array_flip(array_intersect(array_column($arr1,'id'),$arr2));

  foreach ($intersection as $i) {
          var_dump($arr1[$i]);;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

*This answer was migrated from a deleted duplicate. Revised to make sense independent of context.*

Assume the following sample data (named `$items` and `$select` instead of `$arr1` and `$arr2` for clarity):

```
// Source data: A multidimensional array with named keys
$items = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Foo'],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Bar'],
    ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'Maz'],
    ['id' => 6, 'name' => 'Wut'],
];

// Filter values: A flat array of scalar values
$select = [1, 5, 6];
```

Then, how do we extract `$items` with an `id` that matches one of the values in `$select`? And further, how do we do that in a manner that scales gracefully for larger datasets? Let's look at the possibilities and compare their weights.

**1. Optimizing `array_filter()`:**

The answer using `array_filter` certainly gets the job done. However, there's an `in_array` function call made at each iteration. With small datasets, this is hardly an issue. With larger datasets, repeated function calls in an iteration can result in a significant performance hit. Then, for large loops, where possible it's good to "preprocess" data for a lighter operation that uses *language constructs* in place of the more expensive *function calls*.

**How to avoid `in_array()` in loops?**

You can "enable" simple index lookups with `array_flip($select)`, ie. by swapping keys and values, and then using `isset` (*language construct, not a function!*): `isset($select[$id])`. This performs significantly better than repetitions of `in_array($id, $select)` for larger datasets; not only for lack of function call, but at each iteration, `in_array` scans over the `$select` array for matches (over and over). Optimized as follows:

```
$select = array_flip($select);
$selected_items = array_filter($items, function($item) use ($select) {
    return isset($select[$item['id']]);
});
```

Or using an arrow function that includes the parent scope, ie. doesn't need the `use` statement:

```
$select = array_flip($select);
$selected_items = array_filter($items, fn($item) => isset($select[$item['id']]));
```

---

**2. Using Key Intersection**

One elegant alternative to filtering is *key intersection*. First, we *re-index the array by the desired lookup key* using [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/array_column), with `null` for column key (returns full array instead of a specific column), and with `id` for the new index key:

```
$items_by_id = array_column($items, null, 'id');
```

This gives you the same source array, but instead of being zero-indexed, it now uses the `id` column's value for the index key. Then, we're an [`array_intersect_key`](https://www.php.net/array_intersect_key()) away from extracting the *selection* from the *source array*:

```
$selected_items = array_intersect_key($items_by_id, array_flip($select));
```

Here we flip the `$select` to intersect keys. Note that `array_intersect_key` performs better than approaches using `array_intersect`. (Keys are simple!) Result as expected. [See demo](https://3v4l.org/PZstq#v8.2.4) of this approach. Finally, here's a one-liner (formatted for easy reading) without the throw-away variable:

```
$selected_items = array_intersect_key(
    array_column($items, null, 'id'), 
    array_flip($select)
);
```

N.B. The resulting array will retain the actual `id` of the item for its index key; instead of the default zero-indexed keys. Keep that in mind if you cross-reference the selected items with your source array later on in your code; and perhaps index items by the proper ID from the beginning.

---

**Comparing these approaches:**

`array_filter()` incurs 1 iteration of `$items` with 1 (anonymous) function call per each array member; and then as many iterations of `$select` as there are items, if `in_array` is used to compare the current item's ID with each `$select` member. (Use key lookups instead.)

The answer using `array_search` in a `foreach` loop suffers from the same weight, resulting in `count($items)` times function calls --- and a whole lot of redundant rounds over the selection/filter array.

The `array_key_intersect` method **1.** iterates over `$items` once (simple reindexing); **2.** iterates over `$select` once (key/value flip); and **3.** iterates over the keys of each for an intersection. `array_intersect_key` sorts both lists and then compares them in parallel, and as such is much more efficient than repeated array scans for each value. (This function exists specifically for getting intersections, ie. finding overlaps, after all.)

---

**3. Good Old Foreach Loop**

Of course a good old `foreach` loop will also work perfectly fine. Again, using `array_flip()` and `isset()` index lookups, rather than `in_array()` or `array_search()`. As follows:

```
$select = array_flip($select);

$selected_items = [];
foreach($items as $key => $val) {
    if (isset($select[$val['id']])) {
        $selected_items[] = $items[$key];
    }
}
```

I'd instinctively use this for large datasets (or long comparison lists) where "bare bones" performance is called for, going by "simpler is better". However, you likely won't see a big difference between this and the *key intersection* approach without massive data to process. *(If someone has compared these methods for PHP 8.x, please share the benchmark results.)*

Comment: @mickmackusa this answer has been migrated (and revised/enlarged) from the deleted duplicate.

Comment: Just so you know, I didn't get pinged by the above comment -- I must be "present" on the actual/individual post to qualify for the ping.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Migrating OP's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47503473/4) from the question to an answer:</sub>

> I got my code to work as follows:
>
> ```php
> $arr1 = new CachedStuff();  // get cache
>
> $resultingArray = [];  // create an empty array to hold rows
> $filter_function = function ($row) use ($arr2) {
>    return (array_search($row['id'], $arr2));
> };
> $resultingArrayIDs = $arr1->GetIds($filter_function, $resultingArray);
> ```
>
> This gives me two outputs: `$resultingArray` & `$resultingArrayIDs`, both of which represent the intersection of `$arr1` and `$arr2`.