# How to remove an entire row in multidimentional array based on another simple array value

Tags: php

i need to compare the value of an array and based on that i need to check another array which is multidimensional , if the value is present in another array , then i need to delete the entire row from it . how to achieve this ?

```
<?php
$a1=array(
array("key1"=>"123","phone"=>"2234567890","val"=>"test1","color"=>"red"),
array("key1"=>"234","phone"=>"2234567890","val"=>"test2","color"=>"green"),
array("key1"=>"312","phone"=>"2234567890","val"=>"test3","color"=>"yellow"),
array("key1"=>"425","phone"=>"2234567890","val"=>"test4","color" => "orange"));

$a2=array("green");

foreach($a1 as $k => $value){
$result = array_diff($value, $a2);
print_r($result);
}

?>
```

I have tried with array_diff , but only that key,val pair is removing .. i need to remove entire row.

`$a2` array has value "green" .. based on this array `$a1` should have only 3 array as output by removing 2nd array of `$a2`.

Comment: Change the implementation of [Keep array rows where a column value is found in a second flat array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47503473/2943403) from `array_uintersect()` to `array_udiff()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you compare values of `color` key:

```
$a1 = array(
    array("key1"=>"123","phone"=>"2234567890","val"=>"test1","color"=>"red"),
    array("key1"=>"234","phone"=>"2234567890","val"=>"test2","color"=>"green"),
    array("key1"=>"312","phone"=>"2234567890","val"=>"test3","color"=>"yellow"),
    array("key1"=>"425","phone"=>"2234567890","val"=>"test4","color" => "orange")
);
$a2 = array("green");

$newArray = array_filter(
    $a1, 
    function($v) use ($a2) { return !in_array($v['color'], $a2); }
);
```

Fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/9A1jf).

Comment: It's an incorrect solution. Why you use $v['color'], the value can be in another key

Comment: @u_mulder for example $a2=array("test4");

Comment: You can always write your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to compare a specific key, then just check if it is in the array and `unset` it:

```
foreach($a1 as $k => $value){
    if(array_intersect($value, $a2)) {
        unset($a1[$k]);
    }
}
```

This would also work for checking an array with multiple values like:

```
$a2 = array("green", "test4");
//or
$a2 = array("green", "red");
```